# How to send json data to server using retrofit?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I want to send JSON data to server which is in the form

```
{
      "comments": "Testing", 
      "quantity": 0, 
      "retailerId": 0, 
      "retailerquote": 0, 
      "subProductId": 999, 
      "unit": "kg", 
      "wholesalerid": 999
}
```

when it actually get posted it will return "ADDED" as response , I don't know whats wrong with that code, it's showing me "Method not allowed".
This is how I am doing it.

```
HashMap<String,String> header = new HashMap<String, String>();
                header.put("Content-type","application/json");
                HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                data.put("comments",comments);
                data.put("quantity",quantity);
                data.put("retailerId",retailerID);
                data.put("retailerquote",retailerQuote);
                data.put("wholesalerId",wholesalerID);
                data.put("unit",unit);
                data.put("subProductId",subProductID);

                Call<RequestQuoteCheck> call = RetrofitBaseAdapter.getCommonPathInterfaceRequestQuote().requestQuoteCheck(data);

                call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<RequestQuoteCheck>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<RequestQuoteCheck> call, Response<RequestQuoteCheck> response) {

                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.message(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<RequestQuoteCheck> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
```

this is base adapter class

```
    public static WebserviceMethods getCommonPathInterfaceRequestQuote() {
        final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        Retrofit restAdapterRequestQuote = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.baseURLforRequestQuote)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
        WebserviceMethods retrofitinterfaces = restAdapterRequestQuote.create(WebserviceMethods.class);
        return retrofitinterfaces;
    }
}
```

and this is webServiceMethods.java file

```
@POST("requestQuoteCheck")
Call<RequestQuoteCheck> requestQuoteCheck(
        @HeaderMap Map<String,String> data );
```

Comment: You can change request method to ```GET``` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by sending the params using multipart

```
@Multipart
@POST("/QuickBroker/broker/uploadDocuments")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadFile(@Part("comments") RequestBody comments,@Part("quantity") RequestBody quantity,@Part("retailerId") RequestBody retailerId,@Part("retailerquote") RequestBody retailerquote,@Part("wholesalerId") RequestBody wholesalerId);
```

And call this like below by passing header

```
RequestBody mobile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), pref.getString(AppConstants.MOBILE_NUMBER,""));
if(body1 != null && body2 != null && body3 != null && body4 != null) {
    RetrofitAPIs retrofitAPIs = RetrofitBuilders.getInstance().getAPIService(RetrofitBuilders.getBaseUrl());

    Call call = retrofitAPIs.uploadFile(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }

    });
}else{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use to pass data in [GSON](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-Gson/article.html) format instant of passing data in String key value pair.

gradle :-

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

write like below

```
@POST("requestQuoteCheck")
Call<RequestQuoteCheck> requestQuoteCheck(
        @Body HashMap<String,String> data );
```

create Interceptor in adapter like below

```
Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request newRequest;

                newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()

                        .addHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
                        .method(chain.request().method(), chain.request().body())
                        .build();

                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            }
        };
```

and adapter like below

```
public static WebserviceMethods getCommonPathInterfaceRequestQuote() {
        final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(interceptor);
                .build();
        Retrofit restAdapterRequestQuote = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.baseURLforRequestQuote)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
        WebserviceMethods retrofitinterfaces = restAdapterRequestQuote.create(WebserviceMethods.class);
        return retrofitinterfaces;
    }
```

**Second Option:**

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("requestQuoteCheck")
Call<RequestQuoteCheck> requestQuoteCheck(
        @Body HashMap<String,String> data );
```

Comment: still not working, same response "METHOD NOT ALLOWED"

Comment: problem implementing Interceptor

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
    HashMap<String, String> header = new HashMap<String, String>();
    header.put("Content-type", "application/json");
    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
    data.put("comments", comments);
    data.put("quantity", quantity);
    data.put("retailerId", retailerID);
    data.put("retailerquote", retailerQuote);
    data.put("wholesalerId", wholesalerID);
    data.put("unit", unit);
    data.put("subProductId", subProductID);

    // edited here
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(data);
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), jsonString);
    Call<RequestQuoteCheck> call = RetrofitBaseAdapter.getCommonPathInterfaceRequestQuote().requestQuoteCheck(body);

    call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<RequestQuoteCheck>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RequestQuoteCheck> call, Response<RequestQuoteCheck> response) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<RequestQuoteCheck> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

request code

```
// edited here ,exchange POST to GET 
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json","Accept: application/json"})
@GET("requestQuoteCheck")
Call<RequestQuoteCheck> requestQuoteCheck(@Body RequestBody body);
```

You must add `Gson`.

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

Comment: @GajendraSinghRathore I changed ```POST``` to ```GET```.